# How to pass context objects as Django url template tag arguments

Tags: python, django, templates

In my django project, I have two model classes - Category & Action. Category is the ForeignKey of Action (all Actions fall under a Category).

Within my django templates, I'd like to be able to pass a context object into a {% url %} tag that accepts a string containing the name of a Category as an argument. So in a perfect world my django template would have a line like:

`<form action="{% url 'actions' {{ category }} %}">`

And when submitted, Django would follow the form to a urlpattern like:

`url(r'^(?P<category_name>\w+)', views.actions, name='actions'),`

But unfortunately it doesn't look like I'm able to nest template filters into template tags. What's an alternate way I can reference the ForeignKey of a Django object within a url tag? Or perhaps a different way to structure my code?

Comment: What's your problem, you need to pass a string into the url which is the name of that category object?? Is it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem is since it's a django template to be used across multiple Categories, the string can't be hardcoded (e.g. I can't just put in 'Category_One' in place of {{ category }} because it wouldn't work if I were trying to access 'Category_Two')

Comment: This question comes up frequently and I don't understand why people think you need to use variable syntax inside a template tag. The [documentation for the `url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) even has several examples of using variables directly.

Comment: In my project, in the details page of an Action there is a button that refreshes the page with the details page of another randomly chosen Action in that same Category. Originally, passing in a filter was the only method I could find for making that button return another Action of the same Category, no matter which detail page you were currently on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context variables are directly usable in [`url` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form action="{% url 'actions' category_name=category %}">
```

Comment: Thank you! This response lead me to realize a different error I had in my code (I was passing a QuerySet instead of an actual object into the variable categorry). Fixing that combined with using this syntax solved the problem!

Comment: I got this message while trying to do this way: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'my_tasks' with keyword arguments '{'toggle_complete': 0}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['mytasks/\\Z']. Passing it in the template like <a class='nav-link' href="{% url 'my_tasks' toggle_complete=0 %}">My Tasks</a>